# Maven project isn't including the dependencies / libraries in IntelliJ IDEA?

Tags: java, maven, dropwizard

https://github.com/SixteenDollars/help

This is the project. If you open it up, and view any of the Java files, none of the libraries / dependencies are included, I get an error saying "Cannot resolve symbol ___" for all the import statements.

Screenshot:
[image]

UPDATE:
Screenshot of mvn clean install error:
[image]

Comment: What do you mean by "none of the libraries / dependencies are included."? I see that you have the imports. And you have the dependencies in pom as well. What's the issue?

Comment: Sorry, check the update

Comment: Can you share a screenshot of the error

Comment: Did you try doing a `mvn dependency:resolve` before compiling?

Comment: Just tried that, didn't work. Also check the OP

Comment: Simply tried to compile on plain command line first?

Answer (score 0):

I've checked the pom.xml in a link to github you've provided.

Maven wise it's not something complicated. So I think you should try the following:

First of all, try to work with maven directly:
Type:

`mvn clean install`

And make sure it finishes successfully. 
This will make sure that the maven part is ok (pom structures, dependency versions and so forth).

Now the IntelliJ part:

IntelliJ can open "pom.xml" file as a project read it and based on the information found in that pom IntelliJ will build its own project model.

Try to open pom.xml "File --> Open..." and then pick the pom.xml
If IntelliJ asks to import it as a project - agree, if it will recognize that something already exists and offers to remove and re-create the project - also say "ok".

After this step you should be good-to-go.

Comment: What happens when you run mvn clean install?

Comment: It downloads a bunch of stuff then ends with a Build Error. I updated the OP with a screenshot of the error. The dependencies still aren't added.